# Migrating from filezilla to proftpd

Tags: linux, debian, filezilla, migration, proftpd

I was assigned to put a Linux file server in place of the existing FileZilla server. I chose the `proftpd`.

Task: Automated migration of 600+ accounts with the mapping of their folders structure and passwords.

I tried `proftpd` + MySQL and several versions of `proftpd` with virtual users. So far, nothing.

FZ stores accounts in an XML file with passwords hashed via MD5 without salt, while `proftpd` uses salted MD5(Unix). I do not realize how to merge them. Maybe there's a possibility to stock `proftpd` virtual users passwords without salt?

Perhaps, someone has an idea, at least where I have to look for further?

Comment: You might be able to use the [`mod_sql_passwd`](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/contrib/mod_sql_passwd.html) ProFTPD module, which allows for using plain MD5 digests (among others).